Return object is not the one declared by signature when invoked through reflection
I have a PagedList<> class which implements an interface called IPagedList<>
The class does not have a public constructor but can be created through a static method called Create
    public static IPagedList<T> Create(IEnumerable<T> items, int pageNumber, int pageSize, int totalItems) {
        Ensure.That.IsNotNull(items);
        Ensure.That.IsNotZeroOrNegative(pageNumber);
        Ensure.That.IsNotZeroOrNegative(pageSize);

        var totalItemCount = totalItems;
        return new PagedList<T>(items, pageNumber, pageSize, totalItemCount);
    }

This method simply invoke the constructor which is declared private protected.
If the Create method is invoked directly the returned object is an IPagedList<T>
However, when the method is invoked through reflection the returned type is a PagedList<T>
This is the code for reflection
var typeToCall = typeof(PagedList<>).MakeGenericType(targetType);
MethodInfo createMethod = typeToCall.GetMethod("Create")!;
dynamic result = createMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { value, pageNumber, pageSize, totalItems })!;
return (IPagedList)result!;


Is this behavior normal? Does it happens because I am using dynamic?
When the created object is returned to the caller, which expects an IPagedList<T> I get an exception that says

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ApiResult1[PagedList1[ProgramResponse]]' to type 'ApiResult1[IPagedList1[ProgramResponse]]'.

   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidCastException_DeserializeUnableToAssignValue(Type typeOfValue, Type declaredType)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.<UnboxOnRead>g__ThrowUnableToCastValue|50_0[T](Object value)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.UnboxOnRead[T](Object value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value, Boolean& isPopulatedValue)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo`1 jsonTypeInfo, Nullable`1 actualByteCount)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 json, JsonTypeInfo`1 jsonTypeInfo)

I am including the full JsonConverter that deserialize the IPagedList object
internal class NativePagedListConverter : JsonConverter<IPagedList> {
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) {
        return typeToConvert.IsPagedList();
    }

    public override IPagedList? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject) {
            throw new JsonException();
        }
        int pageNumber = 0;
        int pageSize = 0;
        int totalItems = 0;
        dynamic value = default!;
        var targetType = typeToConvert.GetGenericArguments()[0]!;
        while (reader.Read()) {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject) {
                break;
            }
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.PropertyName) {
                throw new JsonException();
            }
            var propertyName = reader.GetString() ?? string.Empty;
            reader.Read();
            if (propertyName.Equals(nameof(pageNumber), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                pageNumber = reader.GetInt32();
            }
            else if (propertyName.Equals(nameof(pageSize), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                pageSize = reader.GetInt32();
            }
            else if (propertyName.Equals(nameof(totalItems), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                totalItems = reader.GetInt32();
            }
            else if (propertyName.Equals("Items", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                var itemsType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(targetType);
                value = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, itemsType, options)!;
            }
        }
        var typeToCall = typeof(PagedList<>).MakeGenericType(targetType);
        MethodInfo createMethod = typeToCall.GetMethod("Create")!;
        dynamic result = createMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { value, pageNumber, pageSize, totalItems })!;
        return (IPagedList)result!;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IPagedList value, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
        [...omitted as not interesting for the question...]
    }

}


How specifically are you observing the difference and what problem is it causing?  Both versions return an instance of PagedList<T>, and an instance of PagedList<T> is also of type IPagedList<T>.  Is something failing in one version vs. the other?

I get an exception when calling through reflection. With a very strange message. See the edit as I added more context

@Mammt Please [edit] your question to include the full code you have, where you use the Create() and where you use ApiResult.

ApiResult is a simple class that wrap an Api result. The Create method is called in a custom JsonConverter that you can find attached. If I look at the objects, everything is deserialized correctly

from your code it doesn't look like IPagedList<T> extends the IPagedList (non-generic) you cast to

It does. It give access to the list of elements while IPagedList only declare metadatas. public interface IPagedList<out T> : IPagedList { IReadOnlyList<T> Items { get; } }

@Mammt something doesn't add up. I think you need to include a lot more code. ApiResult, the interfaces, where exactly the exception is thrown (line) etc...

Hard to say what the problem is here.  Might be some problem with covariance, or with polymorphism, or with using the simple converter pattern instead of the factory converter pattern.  We need to see a [mcve] to say for sure.  Here a [mcve] would include 1) Sample implementations of IPagedList, PagedList<T> and related.  2) Some item class T which could be very simple.  3) JSON to deserialize.  4) A call to JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IPagedList<T>>() that throws the exception.

While you haven't shared your implementations of ApiResult<T> or IPagedList<T> or PagedList<T>, this looks to be a case where the factory converter pattern would be required:

The factory pattern is required for open generics because the code to convert an object to and from a string isn't the same for all types. A converter for an open generic type (List<T>, for example) has to create a converter for a closed generic type (List<DateTime>, for example) behind the scenes. Code must be written to handle each closed-generic type that the converter can handle.

Let's say your types look something like this:
public abstract record ApiResult
{
    public static ApiResult<T> Create<T>(T result) => new ApiResult<T>(result);
}

public record ApiResult<T>(T Result) : ApiResult;

public interface IPagedList
{
    public IEnumerable Items { get; }
    public int PageNumber { get; }
    public int PageSize { get; }
    public int TotalItems { get; }
}

public interface IPagedList<out T> : IPagedList
{
    public new IEnumerable<T> Items { get; }
}

public class PagedList<T> : IPagedList<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; }
    public int PageNumber { get; }
    public int PageSize { get; }
    public int TotalItems { get; }
    IEnumerable IPagedList.Items => Items;

    private protected PagedList(IEnumerable<T> items, int pageNumber, int pageSize, int totalItems) =>
        (this.Items, this.PageNumber, this.PageSize, this.TotalItems) = (items, pageNumber, pageSize, totalItems);

    public static IPagedList<T> Create(IEnumerable<T> items, int pageNumber, int pageSize, int totalItems) {
        //Ensure.That.IsNotNull(items);  // FIXED removed calls to undefined methods
        //Ensure.That.IsNotZeroOrNegative(pageNumber);
        //Ensure.That.IsNotZeroOrNegative(pageSize);
        return new PagedList<T>(items, pageNumber, pageSize, totalItems);
    }
}

Then you can define the following factory converter and inner generic converter as follows:
public class PagedListConverter : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeToConvert.IsPagedList();
    
    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(PagedListConverter<>).MakeGenericType(typeToConvert.GetPagedListItemType()!))!;
}

public class PagedListConverter<T> : JsonConverter<IPagedList<T>>
{
    record DTO(IEnumerable<T> items, int pageNumber, int pageSize, int totalItems);

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeToConvert == typeof(IPagedList<T>) || typeToConvert == typeof(PagedList<T>);

    public override IPagedList<T> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DTO>(ref reader, options) switch
        {
            var dto when dto is not null => PagedList<T>.Create(dto.items, dto.pageNumber, dto.pageSize, dto.totalItems),
            _ => PagedList<T>.Create(Enumerable.Empty<T>(), 0, 0, 0), // TODO: decide what to do in case a null value was encountered in the JSON
        };
        
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IPagedList<T> value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, new DTO(value.Items, value.PageNumber, value.PageSize, value.TotalItems), options);
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfacesAndSelf(this Type type)
        => (type ?? throw new ArgumentNullException()).IsInterface ? new[] { type }.Concat(type.GetInterfaces()) : type.GetInterfaces();

    public static bool IsPagedList(this Type type) => type.GetPagedListItemType() != null;
    
    public static Type? GetPagedListItemType(this Type type) => 
        type.GetInterfacesAndSelf()
            .Where(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IPagedList<>))
            .Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments()[0])
            .SingleOrDefault();
}

Now let's say you have some item class e.g. as follows:
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

You will be able to serialize and deserialize a PagedList<MyItem> or IPagedList<MyItem> as follows:
var result = ApiResult.Create(
    PagedList<MyItem>.Create([new () { Name = "name 1", Price = 101.1M }], 3, 1, 20)
);

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new PagedListConverter() },
    // Other options as required, e.g.
    WriteIndented = true,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(result, options);

var newResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ApiResult<IPagedList<MyItem>>>(json, options);

Notes:

In the inner converter, rather than writing and reading each property manually, it can be easier to map the type to be serialized to some inner DTO, then serialize and deserialize the DTO.

The factory converter pattern may not work when using source generation in a native AOT app.  (For instance Type.MakeGenericType() and MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod() are not guaranteed to work in such an app.)  Instead it will be necessary to manually create the inner converter PagedListConverter<T> for all types T, e.g.:
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { 
        new PagedListConverter<MyItem>(),
        // Other PagedListConverter<T> converters as required
    },
    // Other options as required, e.g.
    WriteIndented = true,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
};



Demo fiddle here.

Actually using the factory pattern did the trick. With the factory pattern it is easier when using a generic type as you can work without reflection in most cases. However, still I don't understand why this happened as the reflection code was effectively calling the same method and nothing has changed in the converter. I'll try to create a fiddle to show.

@Mammt - the simple converter might not have worked because of some bug or limitation in MSFT code, e.g. they assume that the declared return type of the Read() method is the same as the property's declared type.
